# How to setup integration test with Spring and Spock?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spock

I have a project with 2 modules, A and B (business logic and rest services) and B depends on A.

Launching the SpringBoot application works, but I cannot setup properly the integration test.

I have an abstract class that extends Spock Specification

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, 
                    classes = [WebAppConfig.class, AppConfig.class])
@WebIntegrationTest
@Stepwise
abstract class RestIntegrationBaseSpec extends Specification {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate()

    String getBasePath() { "" }

    URI serviceURI(String path = "") {
        new URI("http://localhost:8080/${basePath}${path}")
    }
}
```

and I extend it for my test, trying to inject a service that is implemented in module A

```
class TransactionsControllerSpec extends RestIntegrationBaseSpec{

@Override
String getBasePath() {
    //return "api/"
    return ""
}

@Autowired
ImportService importService

def setupSpec() {
    initDB()
}

private void initDB() {
    importService.importData();
}

def "Test"() {
    given:
      ...
    when:
        ...
    then:
        ...
}
```

But I get NullPointerException on importService.importData(), importService is null.

In my gradle file in B project I added these dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-remote-shell')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')
compile project(':business')

// http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.2'

// http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean @Autowired?

Comment: @MattBusche yes, typo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that solves the issue but try adding `@WebAppConfiguration` in the test. This will ensure that the `WebApplicationContext` is loaded for the test.